# How to convert millisecond data in to time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, posixct

```
timeInMSec height  c1
  1     100.0   1
  5     80.0    1
  6     80.0    0
  9     76.0    1
 12     80.5    0
 14     80.5    1
 16     80.5    0
```

I have data like shown above where timeInMsec is time in millisecond and whenever change happens we record quantity. Quantities are classes as well as continuous values so I wanted to perform time series analysis over this kind of data.
so how to convert this kind of irregular data in to time series using R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that "whenever change happens we record quantity", so you can probably expand the series and then fill the value based on the previous observations. After that, you can convert the data frame to time series. If you are looking for more advanced imputation techniques. You can consider functions from the `imputeTS` package.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  # Complete the sequence
  complete(timeInMSec = full_seq(timeInMSec, period = 1)) %>%
  # Fill the value based on previous record
  fill(-timeInMSec)

# Convert to ts object
dat_ts <- ts(dat2[, -1], start = dat2$timeInMSec[1], end = dat2$timeInMSec[16])
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "timeInMSec height  c1
  1     100.0   1
                  5     80.0    1
                  6     80.0    0
                  9     76.0    1
                  12     80.5    0
                  14     80.5    1
                  16     80.5    0",
                  header = TRUE)
```